# how to show different windows in main window?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

- In my c# Wpf standalone application i created Main Window and added to my project another 5 windows
- I put in Main Window a button by name of every window from these 5 windows.
- my question is: when i press any button in Main Window..how to show its related window in (Windows Area) in Main Window?? e.g. if i press history button ..how to show History window in that (Windows Area) of Main Window??
- Note: i don't want to use pages or navigation windows with navigation controls in my application.

[image]

Comment: have you tried tabcontrol?

Comment: is there any specific reason you want to use a `Window` and not a `ContentControl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use UserControl's and add them to your Container Control, when you click your buttons.

Here is a simplistic example:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="History" Height="53" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button Content="Precaution" Height="53" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,12,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button2_Click" />
        <Button Content="Uses" Height="53" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="208,12,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button3_Click" />
        <Button Content="Side Effects" Height="53" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="314,12,0,0" Name="button4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button4_Click" />
        <Button Content="New Item" Height="53" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="405,12,0,0" Name="button5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button5_Click" />
        <Viewbox Height="209" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,90,0,0" Name="Container" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    History use1 = new History();
    Precaution use2 = new Precaution();
    Uses use3 = new Uses();
    SideEffect use4 = new SideEffect();
    NewItem use5 = new NewItem();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Container.Child = use1;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Container.Child = use2;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Container.Child = use3;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Container.Child = use4;
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Container.Child = use5;
    }
}
```

**Dummy UserControls**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.History"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="209" d:DesignWidth="479" Background="AliceBlue">
    <Grid Width="479" Height="209">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Precaution"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="209" d:DesignWidth="479" Background="LightCoral" >
    <Grid Width="479" Height="209">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Uses"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="209" d:DesignWidth="479" Background="LightGreen" >
    <Grid Width="479" Height="209">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.SideEffect"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="209" d:DesignWidth="479" Background="PapayaWhip" >
    <Grid Height="209" Width="479">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.NewItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="209" d:DesignWidth="479" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow">
    <Grid Height="209" Width="479">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: i followed your answer exactly ..but it doesn't work .. i replaced my 5 windows with 5 user controls and copied your codes exactly ..but it doesn't work ..what did u mean with (use UserControl's and add them to your Container Control) how to add my 5 user controls to my container?? should i do something u didn't mention in ur answer???

Comment: @Hatem Everything that you need should be in my answer, it is a simplistic working example. Please add the Xaml for one of your userControls and your MainWindow to your question.

Comment: when i followed your answer and exact codes .. i found along error list appear ... i will show u may be u get what i miss [here](http://www.4shared.com/photo/tpvMofLJ/qq_online.html)

Comment: Sometime wpf can be a bit exasperating when you change namespaces. Is what you trying to use the exact same code that I gave as an example?

Comment: It looks like it is not finding any of the eventhandler or Initializations for the Usercontrols.

Comment: i made a new projectand copy - paste your code to be able to know if i did any mistake ..but i can't understand where is the trouble??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21792/discussion-between-hatem-and-mark-hall)